# How to provide Equal spaces to this FAB in xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, floating-action-button

Please find Image

[image]

> Here is my Layout XML: I am writing this Code for my Application

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FullScreenImageActivity">

        <com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
            android:id="@+id/image11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/navimage" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/download_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/download"
                app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white" />

            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/download_sbtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/download"
                app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white" />
     </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

> Can Anyone Point me out why it is not working
>   Any Suggestions will be Helpful

Comment: what is the issue..? Please give full Description about the Question

Comment: @BADSHAH please see the image link at the Top of this question

Comment: How do you want the Result..?

Comment: equally spaced the FAB in this Bottom Linear Layout

Comment: make linear layout  android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"   @BADSHAH

Comment: @BADSHAH not working !!!

Comment: Pls try this my solution

Answer (score 1):

It would always be better to learn from the official documentation. Here it goes

[WeightSum](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum) documentation:

> Defines the maximum weight sum. If unspecified, the sum is computed by
>   adding the layout_weight of all of the children. This can be used for
>   instance to give a single child 50% of the total available space by
>   giving it a layout_weight of 0.5 and setting the weightSum to 1.0.
>
> May be a floating point value, such as "1.2".

[Layout Weight](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#LinearLayout_Layout_layout_weight) Documentation:

> Indicates how much of the extra space in the LinearLayout is allocated
>   to the view associated with these LayoutParams. Specify 0 if the view
>   should not be stretched. Otherwise the extra pixels will be pro-rated
>   among all views whose weight is greater than 0.
>
> May be a floating point value, such as "1.2".

Answer (score 1):

You have to use something different.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      >

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        .../>

  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      >
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        .../>
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple thing you do. Make Linear layout gravity to center and then give equal margin to FAB.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_back"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_call" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_call" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_call" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]